# How do I group this list of dicts by the same month?

Tags: python

Python newb...
I have a list of dicts that I am trying to organize into the same month & year:

```
[{'date':'2008-04-23','value':'1'},
{'date':'2008-04-01','value':'8'},
{'date':'2008-04-05','value':'3'},
{'date':'2009-04-19','value':'5'},
{'date':'2009-04-21','value':'8'},
{'date':'2010-09-09','value':'3'},
{'date':'2010-09-10','value':'4'},
]
```

What I'm trying to get is a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'date':2008-04-01,'value':'12'},
{'date':2009-04-01,'value':'13'},
{'date':2010-09-01,'value':'7'},
]
```

Here's my code, which is just printing an empty list:

```
from datetime import datetime

myList = [{'date':'2008-04-23','value':'1'}, {'date':'2008-04-01','value':'8'}, {'date':'2008-04-05','value':'3'}, {'date':'2009-04-19','value':'5'}, {'date':'2009-04-21','value':'8'},{'date':'2010-09-09','value':'3'},
    {'date':'2010-09-10','value':'4'},
    ]

newList = []
newDict = {}

for cnt in range(len(myList)):
    for k,v in myList[cnt].iteritems():
        if k == 'date':
            d = datetime.strptime(v,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
            for elem in newList:
                if elem['date'] != d:
                    newList.append({'date':d,'value':myList[cnt]['value']})
                else:
                    newList[cnt]['value'] += myList[cnt]['value']

print newList
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First, I would sort the data<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> lst = [{'date':'2008-04-23','value':'1'},
... {'date':'2008-04-01','value':'8'},
... {'date':'2008-04-05','value':'3'},
... {'date':'2009-04-19','value':'5'},
... {'date':'2009-04-21','value':'8'},
... {'date':'2010-09-09','value':'3'},
... {'date':'2010-09-10','value':'4'},
... ]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x:x['date'][:7])
>>> lst
[{'date': '2008-04-23', 'value': '1'}, {'date': '2008-04-01', 'value': '8'}, {'date': '2008-04-05', 'value': '3'}, {'date': '2009-04-19', 'value': '5'}, {'date': '2009-04-21', 'value': '8'}, {'date': '2010-09-09', 'value': '3'}, {'date': '2010-09-10', 'value': '4'}]
```

Then, I would use `itertools.groupby` to do the grouping:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for k,v in groupby(lst,key=lambda x:x['date'][:7]):
...    print k, list(v)
... 
2008-04 [{'date': '2008-04-23', 'value': '1'}, {'date': '2008-04-01', 'value': '8'}, {'date': '2008-04-05', 'value': '3'}]
2009-04 [{'date': '2009-04-19', 'value': '5'}, {'date': '2009-04-21', 'value': '8'}]
2010-09 [{'date': '2010-09-09', 'value': '3'}, {'date': '2010-09-10', 'value': '4'}]
>>>
```

Now, to get the output you wanted:

```
>>> for k,v in groupby(lst,key=lambda x:x['date'][:7]):
...     print {'date':k+'-01','value':sum(int(d['value']) for d in v)}
... 
{'date': '2008-04-01', 'value': 12}
{'date': '2009-04-01', 'value': 13}
{'date': '2010-09-01', 'value': 7}
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Your data actually already appears to be sorted in this regard, so you might be able to skip this step.</sup>

Comment: +1. But he also apparently wants to sum up the values in each group, and map the result to… any arbitrary date in that month? the 1st of that month?… something.

Comment: @abarnert -- Thanks for pointing that out.  I've added something to address that to my answer...

Comment: Why do you use `[:7]`? Why 7?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos [:7] is used to slice the string an get the first 6 characters of the date string giving you the date in the format YYYY-MM. This format is used as the key for the groupby operation

Answer (score 24):

Use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
data = [{'date':'2008-04-23','value':'1'},
    {'date':'2008-04-01','value':'8'},
    {'date':'2008-04-05','value':'3'},
    {'date':'2009-04-19','value':'5'},
    {'date':'2009-04-21','value':'8'},
    {'date':'2010-09-09','value':'3'},
    {'date':'2010-09-10','value':'4'},
    ]

import itertools

key = lambda datum: datum['date'].rsplit('-', 1)[0]

data.sort(key=key)

result = [{
            'date': key + '-01',
            'value': sum(int(item['value']) for item in group)
           } for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, key=key)]

print result

# [{'date': '2008-04-01', 'value': 12},
#  {'date': '2009-04-01', 'value': 13},
#  {'date': '2010-09-01', 'value': 7}]
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is correct, but its time complexity is O(n lg n) because of the sorting. Here's an (amortized) O(n) solution.

```
>>> L=[{'date':'2008-04-23','value':'1'},
... {'date':'2008-04-01','value':'8'},
... {'date':'2008-04-05','value':'3'},
... {'date':'2009-04-19','value':'5'},
... {'date':'2009-04-21','value':'8'},
... {'date':'2010-09-09','value':'3'},
... {'date':'2010-09-10','value':'4'},
... ]
```

This is what a `Counter` is made for:

```
>>> import collections
>>> value_by_month = collections.Counter()
>>> for d in L:
...     value_by_month[d['date'][:7]+'-01'] += int(d['value'])
...
>>> value_by_month
Counter({'2009-04-01': 13, '2008-04-01': 12, '2010-09-01': 7})
```

And if your output has to be a `dict` object:

```
>>> dict(value_by_month)
{'2008-04-01': 12, '2009-04-01': 13, '2010-09-01': 7}
```

Bonus: if you want to avoid imports.

First, create a dict `month -> list of values`. The function `setdefault` is handy for building this type of dict:

```
>>> values_by_month = {}
>>> for d in L:
...     values_by_month.setdefault(d['date'][:7], []).append(int(d['value']))
...
>>> values_by_month
{'2008-04': [1, 8, 3], '2009-04': [5, 8], '2010-09': [3, 4]}
```

Second, sum the values by month and set the date to first day:

```
>>> [{'date':m+'-01', 'value':sum(vs)} for m, vs in values_by_month.items()]
[{'date': '2008-04-01', 'value': 12}, {'date': '2009-04-01', 'value': 13}, {'date': '2010-09-01', 'value': 7}]
```