# How do I group this list of dicts by the same month? (A follow-up)

Tags: python

I [just asked a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176469/how-do-i-group-this-list-of-dicts-by-the-same-month) and both answers worked. However, when I have > 2 dictionary keys in each dictionary, the value of the 3rd key always comes up as 0. For instance:

```
myList = [{'date':'2008-04-23','value':'1','value2':'2'}, {'date':'2008-04-01','value':'8','value2':'5'}, {'date':'2008-04-05','value':'3','value2':'4'}, {'date':'2009-04-19','value':'5','value2':'1'}, {'date':'2009-04-21','value':'8','value2':'1'},{'date':'2010-09-09','value':'3','value2':'1'},
    {'date':'2010-09-10','value':'4','value2':'9'},
    ]
```

a modified version of mgilson's answer:

```
import itertools
from itertools import groupby
myList.sort(key=lambda x:x['date'][:7])
for k,v in groupby(myList,key=lambda x:x['date'][:7]):
    print k, list(v)
for k,v in groupby(myList,key=lambda x:x['date'][:7]):
    print {'date':k+'-01','value':sum(int(d['value']) for d in v),'value2':sum(int(d['value2']) for d in v)}
```

result:

```
{'date': '2008-04-01', 'value2': 0, 'value': 12}
{'date': '2009-04-01', 'value2': 0, 'value': 13}
{'date': '2010-09-01', 'value2': 0, 'value': 7}
```

A modified version of Pavel's answer:

```
import itertools
key = lambda datum: datum['date'].rsplit('-', 1)[0]
myList.sort(key=key)
result = [{
            'date': key + '-01',
            'value': sum(int(item['value']) for item in group),
            'value2': sum(int(item['value2']) for item in group)
           } for key, group in itertools.groupby(myList, key=key)]

print result
```

result:

```
[{'date': '2008-04-01', 'value2': 0, 'value': 12}, {'date': '2009-04-01', 'value2': 0, 'value': 13}, {'date': '2010-09-01', 'value2': 0, 'value': 7}]
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the same iterator twice:

```
print {'date':k+'-01','value':sum(int(d['value']) for d in v),'value2':sum(int(d['value2']) for d in v)}
```

The first call to `sum` consumes a generator expression that consumes all of `v`. The second call to `sum` consumes a generator expression that consumes whatever's left in `v`, which is… nothing.

There are a few different ways to solve this, but the smallest change is to just turn `v` into a `list` and use that instead:

```
for k, group in groupby(myList,key=lambda x:x['date'][:7]):
    v = list(group)
    print {'date':k+'-01','value':sum(int(d['value']) for d in v),'value2':sum(int(d['value2']) for d in v)}
```

---

The distinction between iterators and iterables can be a bit confusing to the novice. I wish I had a good tutorial to point to on this… But let me try to explain:

An iterator is something you can only iterate over once.

An iterable is anything that can go into a `for` loop, list comprehension, generator expression, etc.—or, more precisely, anything you can call `iter(foo)` on to get an iterable.

Iterators are (usually) also iterables, but the reverse is not necessarily true. In particular, sequences, like `list`s, are iterables that can give you a new iterator over and over.

Comment: it's still a bit blurry to me but your solution works if I change it to v = list(v) (as you explained in your writeup...probably just a typo)

Comment: @user2312507: I also changed the `for` loop to `for k, group` instead of `for k, v`, so `v = list(group)` is right. But of course your way is equivalent.