# Re-structuring a list of Python Dicts using setdefault

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterable, setdefault

I am trying to re-structure a list of Python dictionaries by 'grouping' (that's probably not the correct expression, but using it as a proxy based on SQL) the dictionaries based on a (non-unique) value. I have got close, however I'm falling at the final hurdle, in that I couldn't work out how to re-assign each value to a name (i.e. I end up with what looks like a tuple rather than a dict).

Additionally I have a superfluous list (i.e. my output ends up as [[{...}]] rather than [{...}].

I have used the example here:

[How do I group this list of dicts by the same month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176469/how-do-i-group-this-list-of-dicts-by-the-same-month)

Which gets me quite close to what I want, however I'm stuck at the final stage!

```py
market = [
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'},
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'},
    {'selection_id': 1097, 'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'},
    {'selection_id': 1097, 'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'},
    {'selection_id': 1098, 'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'},
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'},
    {'selection_id': 1098, 'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'},
]

new_structure = {}
new_structure2 = []

for z in market:
        new_structure.setdefault(z['selection_id'], []).append((z['value'], z['value_name']))
        t = [{'selection_id': m, 'value_dict': n} for m, n in new_structure.items()]
new_structure2.append(t)

print(new_structure2)
```

This outputs as:

```py
[[{'selection_id': 1099, 'value_dict': [('11', 'a'), ('78', 'p'), ('13',  
 'y')]}, {'selection_id': 1097, 'value_dict': [('39', 'b'), ('52', 'f')]},  
 {'selection_id': 1098, 'value_dict': [('98', 'd'), ('4', 'r')]}]]
```

Which is very close, however what I'm aiming for is:

```py
[{'selection_id': 1099,
  'value_dict': [{'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'},
                 {'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'},
                 {'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'}]},
 {'selection_id': 1097,
  'value_dict': [{'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'},
                 {'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'}]},
 {'selection_id': 1098,
  'value_dict': [{'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'},
                 {'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'}]}]
```

I appreciate its probably a really simple fix, but its escaping me at the moment, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints:

The first thing is to sort by *selection_id*:

```py
by_selection_id = operator.itemgetter('selection_id')
market.sort(key=by_selection_id)
```

Then you can group by *selection_id*:

```py
for selection_id, group in itertools.groupby(market, key=by_selection_id):
    print(selection_id, list(group))
```

You get:

```py
(1097, [{'value_name': 'b', 'value': '39', 'selection_id': 1097},
        {'value_name': 'f', 'value': '52', 'selection_id': 1097}])
(1098, [{'value_name': 'd', 'value': '98', 'selection_id': 1098},
        {'value_name': 'r', 'value': '4', 'selection_id': 1098}])
(1099, [{'value_name': 'a', 'value': '11', 'selection_id': 1099},
        {'value_name': 'p', 'value': '78', 'selection_id': 1099},
        {'value_name': 'y', 'value': '13', 'selection_id': 1099}])
```

Then it is easy to build the final list.

Here is a solution using comprehension list/dict:

```py
new_structure = [{'selection_id': selection_id,
                  'value_dict': [{'value': item['value'],
                                  'value_name': item['value_name']} for item in group]}
                 for selection_id, group in itertools.groupby(market, key=by_selection_id)]
```

Or using a classic list with `append`:

```py
new_structure = []
for selection_id, group in itertools.groupby(market, key=by_selection_id):
    value_dict = [{'value': item['value'], 'value_name': item['value_name']} for item in group]
    new_structure.append({'selection_id': selection_id,
                          'value_dict': value_dict})
```

Comment: That uses a sort. The mention of setdefault recalls the hash join that does not use a sort.

Comment: @DanD. Agree. And, instead of using `setdefault`, the OP can use `collection.defaultdict(list)`. There are many ways to do that… There are also solutions using [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/).

Comment: Cool thank you for this alternative approach, I've got it working (see below) with a bit of assistance, using my original approach. But its really helpful to see an alternative way of doing things to learn from, so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I end up with what looks like a tuple rather than a dict)

This is because you are appending a tuple, not a dict:

```
.append((z['value'], z['value_name']))
```

Comment: Yes :-) Perhaps badly phrased on my part, when I tried to append as a dict, I couldn't get it working (and wasn't sure if this was due to my syntax or whether it wasn't possible within setdefault)

Comment: @always_confused I suggest you try again. If you are unable to get it to work, post the code you attempt to do so along with any error messages you get.

Comment: Ah, yes not sure what I did before, but using the following:

`for z in market:  
#        new_structure.setdefault(z['selection_id'], []).append((z['value'], z['value_name']))
        new_structure.setdefault(z['selection_id'], []).append({'value': z['value'], 'value_name': z['value_name']})
        t = [{'selection_id': m, 'value_dict': n} for m, n in new_structure.items()]
new_structure2.append(t)

print(new_structure2)`

I get there...although I still end up with the superflous list (presumably created on the line t=...but not sure how else to re-structure that bit):

Comment: `
[[{'selection_id': 1099, 'value_dict': [{'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'}, {'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'}, {'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'}]}, {'selection_id': 1097, 'value_dict': [{'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'}, {'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'}]}, {'selection_id': 1098, 'value_dict': [{'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'}, {'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'}]}]]
`

(Sorry I can never seem to get line breaks to work in this section)

Comment: @always_confused Comments don't allow code formatting. I suggest that you post an answer showing your solution.

Comment: @always_confused If your code still isn't quite giving the results you want, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to update, based on the answer from @Code-Apprentice, I have re-written my code as follows:

```py
market = [
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'},
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'},
    {'selection_id': 1097, 'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'},
    {'selection_id': 1097, 'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'},
    {'selection_id': 1098, 'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'},
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'},
    {'selection_id': 1098, 'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'},
]

new_structure = {}
new_structure2 = []

for z in market:
    new_structure.setdefault(z['selection_id'], []).append({'value': z['value'],
                                                            'value_name': z['value_name']})
    t = [{'selection_id': m, 'value_dict': n} for m, n in new_structure.items()]
    new_structure2.append(t)

print(new_structure2)
```

Which then gets me very close to my desired output. The only remaining issue I have, is a superfluous list (i.e. [[{....}]] instead of [{...}]), I believe this is probably because of the way I have written the line t=....

Here is my output, I will post an update, once I've got rid of that extra list in case the answer is of use to anyone else (but please feel free to shout if you spot it before me):

```py
[[{'selection_id': 1099,
   'value_dict': [{'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'},
                  {'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'},
                  {'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'}]},
  {'selection_id': 1097,
   'value_dict': [{'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'},
                  {'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'}]},
  {'selection_id': 1098,
   'value_dict': [{'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'},
                  {'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'}]}]]
```

So ridiculously basic! I was over-complicating it, just simply removed the extra list reference:

```py
market = [
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'},
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'},
    {'selection_id': 1097, 'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'},
    {'selection_id': 1097, 'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'},
    {'selection_id': 1098, 'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'},
    {'selection_id': 1099, 'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'},
    {'selection_id': 1098, 'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'},
]

new_structure = {}

for z in market:
    new_structure.setdefault(z['selection_id'], []).append({'value': z['value'],
                                                            'value_name': z['value_name']})

new_structure2 = [{'selection_id': m, 'value_dict': n} for m, n in new_structure.items()]
```

Comment: You can also use `new_structure = collections.defaultdict(list)` and then `new_structure[z['selection_id']].append(...)`.