# How to move 2 keys / values in a Nested Dict up one level in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, nested

Yesterday I had an issue with regards to re-structuring a list of dicts here (I mention in case it helps anyone else having a similar problem):

[Re-structuring a list of Python Dicts using setdefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156089/re-structuring-a-list-of-python-dicts-using-setdefault)

However, I omitted one (now seemingly key) part of the data. Initially I thought it would be easy to add in extra dictionary keys later on, however this has proved troublesome with the structure. Hence I have come up with the following way, of getting close to what I require.

In essence I am looking to move the 2 keys 'selection_id' and 'other_data' up one level and completely replace the 'market_data' dictionary (see ideal data structure below).

I thought I could find a way using setattr, but that appears to be problematic in loops, with nested dictionaries. Also I'm not even sure that was an appropriate way, given I will receive all the data anyway up front, just in the wrong format.

My sample code, which gets close is shown below:

```
market=[{'selection_id': 1099,'value':'11', 'value_name': 'a', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1099,'value':'78', 'value_name': 'p', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1097,'value':'39', 'value_name': 'b', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1097,'value':'52', 'value_name': 'f', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1098,'value':'98', 'value_name': 'd', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1099,'value':'13', 'value_name': 'y', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1098,'value':'4', 'value_name': 'r', 'other_data': 89},
]

new_structure = {}  

new_structure2 = []  


for z in market:
        new_structure.setdefault((z['selection_id'], z['other_data']), []).append({'value': z['value'], 'value_name': z['value_name']})
new_structure2.append([{'market_data': m, 'value_dict': n} for m, n in new_structure.items()])

for s in new_structure2:
    for t in s:
        dict = {}
        dict['selection_id'] = t['market_data'][0]
        dict['other_data'] = t['market_data'][1]
        t['market_data'] = dict

print(new_structure2)
```

The above code produces the following:

```
[[{'market_data':  
{'selection_id': 1099, 'other_data': 89}, 'value_dict':  
[{'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'}, {'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'}, {'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'}]},  
{'market_data':  
{'selection_id': 1097, 'other_data': 89}, 'value_dict':  
[{'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'}, {'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'}]}, {'market_data':  
{'selection_id': 1098, 'other_data': 89}, 'value_dict':  
[{'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'}, {'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'}]}]]
```

Whereas what I am looking for is:

```
[{'selection_id': 1099, 'other_data': 89, 'value_dict':  
[{'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'}, {'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'}, {'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'}]},  
{'selection_id': 1097, 'other_data': 89, 'value_dict':  
[{'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'}, {'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'}]},  
{'selection_id': 1098, 'other_data': 89, 'value_dict':  
[{'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'}, {'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'}]}]
```

For the avoidance of doubt, 'other_data' will always be the same for any given 'selection_id', i.e. if there are 2 instances of 'selection_id' = 1099 then 'other_data' will always equal 89 for these (in the example they are all 89, but could be different for different selection_id's in reality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
market=[{'selection_id': 1099,'value':'11', 'value_name': 'a', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1099,'value':'78', 'value_name': 'p', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1097,'value':'39', 'value_name': 'b', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1097,'value':'52', 'value_name': 'f', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1098,'value':'98', 'value_name': 'd', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1099,'value':'13', 'value_name': 'y', 'other_data': 89},  
{'selection_id': 1098,'value':'4', 'value_name': 'r', 'other_data': 89},
]

result = {}
for i in market:
    if i["selection_id"] not in result:
        result[i["selection_id"]] = {'selection_id': i["selection_id"], 'other_data': i["other_data"], 'value_dict': []}
    result[i["selection_id"]]["value_dict"].append({'value': i["value"], "value_name": i["value_name"]})


print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'other_data': 89,
  'selection_id': 1097,
  'value_dict': [{'value': '39', 'value_name': 'b'},
                 {'value': '52', 'value_name': 'f'}]},
 {'other_data': 89,
  'selection_id': 1098,
  'value_dict': [{'value': '98', 'value_name': 'd'},
                 {'value': '4', 'value_name': 'r'}]},
 {'other_data': 89,
  'selection_id': 1099,
  'value_dict': [{'value': '11', 'value_name': 'a'},
                 {'value': '78', 'value_name': 'p'},
                 {'value': '13', 'value_name': 'y'}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you, using my test data I'm able to perfectly able to replicate what you have here...however using the actual data I get (i.e. dynamically), I have a problem as the list(result.values()) creates another list, which doesn't work with how I need to pass on the data. I effectively want just results.values(), but that doesn't work without the list function before it (which I then would append to an already existing list). Is there a way to somehow append to a list, without first adding the extra list?

Comment: Its a bit tricky to decipher the debug, but I think the related error is: TypeError: Object of type dict_values is not JSON serializable (if I don't use list).

Comment: Actually I can just use extend instead of append thinking about it! Although it looks like my data structure is wrong anyway, so may need to re-think, however with your help here that will be much much easier, so many thanks!

Comment: I managed to adapt to fit in with my live environment, it was a simple tweak in the end, but pointless to post here as its not relevant to the original data set I posted, (have already marked as answered).