# How do I create a nested format json from the list of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, pydictionary

create a dictionary in a list of dictionaries

[How do I group this list of dicts by the same month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176469/how-do-i-group-this-list-of-dicts-by-the-same-month). Tried to implement the answer from this link but no luck. would appreciate help.

Here's the list of dictionary format, I have

```
[
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '1','dept': '20020','CNT' : '1','rep_level' : 'form1'},
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '1','dept': '20020','CNT' : '0','rep_level' : 'form2'},
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '1','dept': '20020','CNT' : '4','rep_level' : 'form3'},
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '2','dept': '20020','CNT' : '9','rep_level' : 'all'},
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '3','dept': '20021','CNT' : '14','rep_level' : 'all'},
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '1','dept': '20022','CNT' : '5','rep_level' : 'form1'},
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '1','dept': '20022','CNT' : '2','rep_level' : 'form2'},
{'date':'2020-02-02','id' : '1','dept': '20022','CNT' : '3','rep_level' : 'form3'}
]
```

answer format:

```
[
{"dept":"20020", "date":"2020-02-02", "answers":[{"id":"1", "answerValue":[1,0,4]},{"id":"2", answer:9}]},
{"dept":"20021", "date":"2020-02-02", "answers":[{"id":"3", "answerValue":14}]},
{"dept":"20022", "date":"2020-02-02", "answers":[{"id":"1", "answerValue":[5,2,3]}]}
]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are there ever two dates for a single department? If so, how does that change the desired result? The `rep_level` is never important?

Comment: @Grismar, the date is same for all the dictionaries in the list.

Comment: @Grismar, the rep_level is not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided in the answer you linked is correct, but you have to put it all together in a specific way to get the result you're after:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '1', 'dept': '20020', 'CNT': '1', 'rep_level': 'form1'},
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '1', 'dept': '20020', 'CNT': '0', 'rep_level': 'form2'},
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '1', 'dept': '20020', 'CNT': '4', 'rep_level': 'form3'},
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '2', 'dept': '20020', 'CNT': '9', 'rep_level': 'all'},
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '3', 'dept': '20021', 'CNT': '14', 'rep_level': 'all'},
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '1', 'dept': '20022', 'CNT': '5', 'rep_level': 'form1'},
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '1', 'dept': '20022', 'CNT': '2', 'rep_level': 'form2'},
    {'date': '2020-02-02', 'id': '1', 'dept': '20022', 'CNT': '3', 'rep_level': 'form3'}
]

result = [{
    'dept': dept,
    'answers': [{
        'id': identifier,
        'answerValue': [int(a['CNT']) for a in answers]
    } for identifier, answers in groupby(results, key=lambda x: x['id'])]
} for dept, results in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['dept'])]
```

On the inside, there's:

```
        'answerValue': [int(a['CNT']) for a in answers]
```

Which constructs a list of the answer integer values from string values for `'CNT'` in `answers`, as a list comprehension.

That `answers` comes from the expression around it:

```
    'answers': [{
        'id': identifier,
        'answerValue': [int(a['CNT']) for a in answers]
    } for identifier, answers in groupby(results, key=lambda x: x['id'])]
```

This is another list comprehension, creating one dictionary for each value of `identifier` and the `answers` that come with it, after a call to `groupby()`, grouping `results` on the `'id'` field.

And that `results` comes from the outer comprehension:

```
result = [{
    'dept': dept,
    'answers': [{
        'id': identifier,
        'answerValue': [int(a['CNT']) for a in answers]
    } for identifier, answers in groupby(results, key=lambda x: x['id'])]
} for dept, results in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['dept'])]
```

This is similar to the previous, grouping the original `data` by `'dept'` and creating one dictionary for each department and the `results` grouped for it.

If you `print(result)`:

```
[{'dept': '20020', 'answers': [{'id': '1', 'answerValue': [1, 0, 4]}, {'id': '2', 'answerValue': [9]}]}, {'dept': '20021', 'answers': [{'id': '3', 'answerValue': [14]}]}, {'dept': '20022', 'answers': [{'id': '1', 'answerValue': [5, 2, 3]}]}]
```

Which is the result you were after. You could of course add the date, if you wanted to, but you indicated this is always the same anyway.

Note: personally, I think this is a more useful way of doing something similar:

```
result = {
    dept: {
        identifier: [int(a['CNT']) for a in answers]
        for identifier, answers in groupby(results, key=lambda x: x['id'])
    }
    for dept, results in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['dept'])
}
```

This gets you (when printed):

```
{'20020': {'1': [1, 0, 4], '2': [9]}, '20021': {'3': [14]}, '20022': {'1': [5, 2, 3]}}
```

And you could access that like this:

```
print(result['20020']['2'])  # prints "[9]"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. For single value, I dont want the integer to be in an array. for e.g) I want it to be {'20020': {'1': [1, 0, 4], '2': 9}} instead of {'20020': {'1': [1, 0, 4], '2': [9]}}. May I know how do I do it?

Comment: I'd recommend against doing that, since you'll end up writing extra code that has to check whether to find a list or a single integer as a value. As a programmer, don't look at data like this as a human, look at it like a computer. In this case, it'd be tricky as the object returned by `groupby` doesn't make it very easy to see how many items are in it, since it is an `iter()` on the inside. Easiest would be to replace the single elements after the fact, but that's a lot of extra code to make the result arguably worse.